# Check if an object contains any element of another object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two objects that has similar values except that one contains string values and the other integer values.

```js
var ids = ["1", "5", "3"]
var items = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
]
var items2 = [
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to check if any `id` key in the object `items` contains the same value from `ids`. So if `ids` contains "1" and that `items` has any `id` that also has 1, the function should return true

This is what I tried so far:

```js
function checkIfValueExists(a, b) {
  if (a.some(i => i.includes(b.toString))) {
    console.log("value found")
    return true
  } else {
    console.log("value not found")
    return false
  }
}

checkIfValueExists(ids, items) // should console.log("value found") and returns true
checkIfValueExists(ids, items2) // should return false
```

How can I achieve this using JavaScript/ES6?

Comment: `.toString` is a method so it's `.toString()`

Comment: `b` is an array of objects. What do you expect `b.toString()` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `some` and `includes`. Apply the `some()` method on the on the items array and then convert the `id` of each item into string using `toString` and then use `includes` on `ids`.

```js
var ids = ["1", "5", "3"];var items = [  {    id: 1  },  {    id: 2  },  {    id: 4  }];var items2 = [  {    id: 2  },  {    id: 4  }];

const checkIfValueExists = (ids, items) => items.some(item => ids.includes(item.id.toString()))

console.log(checkIfValueExists(ids, items)) // should console.log("value found") and returns true
console.log(checkIfValueExists(ids, items2)) // should return false
```